# Random intercepts don't change in Mixed Linear Model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am running a fairly simple Linear Mixed Model using nlme package in R.
My design is a set of 12 different tree communities replicated in 3 blocks.
I want to know if the number of species (SR) and a community trait (e.g. wood density, WD) are affecting my fungi/bacteria ratio (FB).
So a sample of my data looks like this:

```
BLOCK SR      ID Community        WD  FB.ratio      AWCD      DHG
1      A  1  F2 P11         D 0.5000000 0.6678064 0.3178387 14.54000
2      A  2  F2 P18        AC 0.6216220 0.6310566 0.3056129 23.01996
3      A  2  F2 P19        AR 0.5485055 0.6849291 0.3286774 18.49884
14     B  2  F3 P14        SC 0.7115013 0.6586879 0.4928387 18.19838
23     B  2  F3 P44        DR 0.5126056 0.5693229 0.4547097 25.10737
24     B  2   F3 P9       Sda 0.6041351 0.6150823 0.3435161 21.88032
25     C  2 F7  P21        AR 0.5420469 0.7044819 0.2892258 25.29704
26     C  2 F7  P33        AC 0.5883944 0.6659611 0.3252903 28.48688
36     C  1   F7 P8         C 0.6500000 0.6150468 0.6928387 27.62000
```

I used

```
FB_SR=lme(FB.ratio~SR+WD,random=~1|BLOCK,data=Microbes)
```

I was expecting that the intercepts would change per block, but when I ask for the coefficients

```
> coef(FB_SR)
```

this is what I get:

```
  (Intercept)          SR         WD
A   0.8241134 -0.01080885 -0.3032058
B   0.8241134 -0.01080885 -0.3032058
C   0.8241134 -0.01080885 -0.3032058
```

Not sure if I'm missing something. 
Would be nice to hear your opinion and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please format the text of the question somehow? This is simply a mess.

Comment: Sorry, I was new to this blog and got the editing wrong. Thank you Whuber.

Comment: Look at `summary(FB_SR)`. I guess the variance of the random effect is estimated to be zero.

Comment: agree with @amoeba, especially because 3 blocks is not very many

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, the low number of blocks was also my first thought. I gave a better look and the intercepts do change but at 1E-11.